# KDE Dolphin file manager: Configure Places for all users

Tags: dual-boot, kde, disk, dolphin

I'm running a dual boot system with Windows 7 - so have a bunch of NTFS and FAT drives - C:, D: and E:

I also have 2 more users for whom I've set up accounts

I've managed to add fstab entries so that the drives are mounted and all users can read/write to these drives

What I'd like to do is be able to add 'friendly' places nodes in Dolphin so that all users see D-Drive, C-Drive, E-Drive rather than the volume label or disk blk id.

I've added it to my account and can see the config file in `~/.local/share/user-places.xbel` - but would like to know what's the best way to do this for 'All users' by default?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

one simple way is of course to just copy the places config file `~/.local/share/user-places.xbel` to the home directory for each user.

Sufficient for me right now.